# iOS: How to cover entire button with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am currently working on a iOS application where I am constantly changing the pictures of two buttons. The problem is that the picture of the button that constantly changes does not stretch over the entire button. I was wondering  what is the best way of doing this.
I believe I am setting my image of my button normally and I cant figure out what to do. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",      [orangeImageArray objectAtIndex:randomPicture2]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Try like this     leftButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your button type `UIButtonTypeCustom` ?

example :

```
 UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [leftButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
 [leftButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code enables you to customize the button well:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(prefer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```